# removing SSLv3 does not seem to fix POODLE problem

Tags: apache, centos

I have removed SSLv3 from my Apache 2.2.15 ssl.conf file with the line

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

I have restarted httpd but POODLE tests still show vulnerability exists with POODLE.
What else could be the issue? Thanks

Comment: SSL is not disabled then!

Comment: @Lighty: That does not answer the question - i.e. what disables SSLv3 if -SSLv3 does not?

Comment: @pi. what test are you using?

Comment: I have used; http://www.poodlescan.com/ for example and shell based tests available at: https://raymii.org/s/articles/Check_servers_for_the_Poodle_bug.html

Comment: @pi. its a comment, not an awnser, but people are suggesting using the -SSLv3 command might not work fully

Comment: You know, these security bugs are starting to sound like a sick pet. _"I'm shellshocked that my poodle has heartbleed"_

Comment: pi - check the q migrated to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162478/poodle-disabling-sslv3-in-apache

Answer (score 0):

You must first look at all configuration files if SSLv3 is enabled on some vhost:

```
grep -i -r "SSLProtocol" /etc/apache
```

Take the list of files `grep` found, and edit the configuration as bellow:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol TLSv1
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:HIGH:!ADH
```

Restart Apache afterwards and it must work.

Comment: Thanks but that did not seem to work either. What apparently worked was placing the SSLProtocol lines within the virtualhost block itself. Crazy

Comment: @pi well that should be obvious, since virtualhost configurations are per-host specific web server settings....